# Connect local IP camera to cloud VPS via Openvpn tunnel using DNAT and SNAT

Tags: iptables, openvpn, port-forwarding, nat, iproute

I'm running two IP cameras on my local network with RTSP turned on. I have zoneminder (camera recorder) hosted on my local network and camera streaming directly to it using RTSP. However, I need to deploy zoneminder in my cloud vps and stream RTSP feed directly to it so I can view my cameras anywhere. ( I know I can still view my local zoneminder using openvpn but I prefer not to)

I setup openvpn server and zoneminder on my cloud vps. And I configured the client on Raspberry pi (with route no-exec) which sitting in the same network as my IP cameras.

Then I enable IP forwarding on my raspberry pi and added below two rules for DNAT and SNAT

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp -i tun0 --dport 3354 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.5.10:8554

iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p udp -s 192.168.5.10 --sport 8554 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.100.50:3354
```

Network details as follows

```
Local network - 192.168.5.0/24
VPN network - 192.168.100.0/24
Raspberry pi local IP - 192.168.5.9
IP camera IP - 192.168.5.10
Raspberry pi VPN IP - 192.168.100.50
VPN sever IP - 192.168.100.1
RTSP port - 8554
```

But when I try to add a camera to zoenminder on my cloud VPS it always fails with error unable to reach the camera. I use below RTSP link to add camera

```
rtsp://192.168.100.50:3354/unicast
```

error form zoneminder

```
Unable to open input rtsp://192.168.100.50:3354/unicast
```

when I do a port scan using Nmap I get something like this

```
3354/udp open|filtered suitjd
```

where did I configure wrong?. basically I need direct communication to my local network items via vpn tunnel. How can I achieve this with any other methods

Comment: RTSP requires special handling when using NAT (like the FTP protocol requires), eg by using the raspbian package [nat-rtsp-dkms](https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nat-rtsp/). I think you have other problems, but this one is an obvious one.